# "Git clone" on Windows 10. I get the prompt "[port number] is not a git command"

Tags: git, syntax, windows-10, git-clone

I am working with Git on Windows 10 and I am getting very frustrated at an error that I get not only on the windows shell, but also on the PowerShell, Git Bash and the Cygwin terminal.

I want to clone a Gerrit repository like so:

`git clone "ssh://[username]@[host]:[port_number]/repository"`

And I always get the following error message

`git: '[port number]' is not a git command. See git --help`

For example (not the real code but very similar):

`git clone "ssh://aruiz@swrepo4:29418/testing/ecutests"`

I get

`git: '29418' is not a git command. See git --help`

Why the windows interpreter constantly understands the port number as a git argument is beyond me. In any case, I would like to ask if any of you might know the cause of this. Unfortunatelly I could not find any other people on the internet with the same problem.

**08/12/2020 UPDATE**: It's finally working! Here is what I changed and I **believe** it is what was causing the problem: Environment variable 'GIT_SSH' was pointing to git.exe. I changed it to ssh.exe (C:\Users<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\usr\bin\ssh.exe). I also updated to the last Git version: 2.29.2.windows.2

Comment: It would be helpful to see the exact command. I understand you might not want to show the user name and host name, but perhaps you could show a command with sample values (like `user` and `example.com`) rather than `[username]` and `[host`]. My guess is that there are some shell meta-characters in some of the values you're using (though the double quotes *should* avoid that).

Comment: Let's say it looks something like this (although not exactly)

git clone "ssh://aruiz@swrepo4:29418/testing/ecutests"

Comment: Please put that in the question. And I tried copy-and-pasting that command and didn't get that error, just "ssh: Could not resolve hostname swrepo4". Are you sure there are no funny characters in any of the username, host, port number, or repository? Do you get the same error if you type *exactly* `git clone "ssh://aruiz@swrepo4:29418/testing/ecutests"`? If not, please include in the question an exact command that produces the error message, and the exact text of the error message. You should be able to reproduce it without revealing sensitive information.

Comment: I modified the question as you asked. Also, for further information: my boss did run this command on his computer and it did work, so something weird must be happening in my session...

Comment: To be clear, when you enter the exact command in your question into git bash and the Cygwin terminal, do you get that exact message? What is the output of `git --version`? `type git`? `printf "%s\n" git clone "ssh://aruiz@swrepo4:29418/testing/ecutests"` ?

Comment: **Git bash**:  
git --version: 2.28.0.windows.1  
type git: git is hashed (/mingw64/bin/git)  
printf "%s\n": I get an empty line  
  
  
**Cygwin terminal**:  
git --version: 2.28.0.windows.1  
type git: git is hashed (/cygdrive/c/Users/ARus/AppData/Local/Programs/Git/cmd/git)   
printf "%s\n": I get an empty line.
This is what I get. I don't know if it will be of any help. In the case of "git clone..." I always get the "29417 is not a git command" prompt

Comment: The command I asked you to try was `printf "%s\n" git clone "ssh://aruiz@swrepo4:29418/testing/ecutests"`

Comment: Oh, ok. In both cases I get git, clone and the whole ssh url in separate lines

Comment: That seems to confirm that the `git` command is seeing `clone` and `ssh://aruiz@swrepo4:29418/testing/ecutests` as its two command-line arguments -- and somehow it's picking `29418` out of that and treating it as a command (the first argument after any options). I've even tried looking through the git sources and I can't see how that could happen. Could it be you have something odd in your `.gitconfig`? Try temporarily renaming `$HOME/.gitconfig` to something else and running the `git clone ...` command again.

Comment: And just to be sure you're not mis-typing something, copy-and-paste the `git clone ...` command *from this question* and running it.

Comment: If I rename .gitconfig, the clone process cannot happen because ssh.variant needs to be ssh to be able to identify a port number.
Some info that might be of interest: If I try git clone not with a ssh:// url but with a https://, it works perfectly normal!
Also, if I try git clone with the ssh:// url but removing the port number like so `git clone "ssh://aruiz@swrepo4:29418/testing/ecutests"`,  (I was just trying random stuff), the message I get is `git: aruiz@swrepo4 is not a git command`.

Comment: Seeing how this error is apparently very weird, I will take some time and write Git support as well. I will let you know if they were able to spot the problem :)

Comment: I don't specify `ssh.variant` in my `.gitconfig`. But what if you temporarily replace your `.gitconfig` with one that specifies only `ssh.variant`? Yeah, this is weird. https://giphy.com/gifs/bobs-burgers-l0HlIbzTDGWY0ySly

Comment: In your comment 12 hours ago, you said you tried it without the port number, but then showed a command that included a port number. It almost looks like `git` just isn't seeing the first argument `clone` -- but then it's somehow extracting the port number of the next argument to complain about it. Do you have anything odd in your `.gitconfig`, particularly aliases?

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant to write that when I type `git clone "ssh://aruiz@swrepo4:/testing/ecutests"` I get `git: aruiz@swrepo4 is not a git command`. Also, I'm only leaving "[ssh] variant = ssh" in .gitconfig and I still get the stupid error :(

Comment: Just to grasp at one more straw, what does `git clone clone "ssh://aruiz@swrepo4:/testing/ecutests"` give you? And do you have a system-wide config file like `/etc/gitconfig`?

Comment: I did indeed find a system level .gitconfig with a lot of options that I have just disabled, same as with the global gitconfig (except for the ssh variant option). Unfortunatelly, I keep having the same error.
When I write `git clone clone "ssh://aruiz@swrepo4:/testing/ecutests"` I get the prompt `fatal: repository 'clone' does not exist`

Comment: How about `git fnord "ssh://aruiz@swrepo4:/testing/ecutests"`. ("fnord" is deliberately chosen to be invalid.)

Comment: In that case I get `git: 'fnord' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.`

Answer (score 0):

But why you need double quotes (`"`) in the `git clone`-command? You don't need this. Try it as follow, without *double quotes*:

```
git clone ssh://<username>@<gerrit-server>:29418/project-name.git
```

On this way, the port-number (in Gerrit by default listening on port 29418 for SSH access) will recognized as a *git command*!

Comment: Why would removing the quotes solve the problem?  In bash, there are no shell metacharacters in `ssh://<username>@<gerrit-server>:29418/project-name.git`, so the `git` command should see exactly the same thing with or without double quotes. (It might be different for Windows cmd and powershell, but the OP says the problem happens with bash as well.)

Comment: @KeithThompson -> please read the question: "...an error that I get **not only** on the **windows shell**, but also on the **PowerShell**, **Git Bash** and the **Cygwin** terminal." There the OP never said, that it's just happens in bash...

Comment: I know it doesn't happen *only* on bash. My point is that, given the information we have, there's no reason to think that removing the double quotes would fix the problem *on bash*. I'm convinced the problem is in the user's actual command, which we haven't seen; the OP has only shown us a summary.

Comment: Yes, and without the *real*-command, we can't really help. But I have never seen double quotes in `git clone` like in OP's *example*-command

Comment: 1. I get exactly the same prompt when removing the quotes
2. The command looks like so:
git clone "ssh://aruiz@swrepo4:29418/testing/ecutests"